# Multiple targets on same project with Swift code

Tags: ios, xcode

In a project I've several target: `MyProject` and `MyProject.Beta`

My project compiles successfully with the target `MyProject` but when I try to compile with the target `MyProject.Beta`, I've this error: `'MyProject-Swift.h' file not found`.

After few investigations in `Build Settings` in the target `MyProject.Beta` I didn't found `Product Module Name` neither `Defines Module` and I've no idea on how can I add them to `Build Settings`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: if you have added MyProject-Swift.h check that it is added for both tragets

Comment: `MyProject-Swift.h` is a generated header file that permits to use Swift code in Objective-C. So it's not included in `Build Phases -> Compile Sources`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below two project settings in `MyProject.Beta`

1. Name of Objective-C generated file name

[image]

2. Name of the module name. You can set the module name as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: I ended up by removing references and reinserting my Swift files in my project and I checked both targets when importing. Then, the `Build Settings` has been updated with values for `Product Module Name` and `Defines Module`.